# Problems with BreezeJS + EF Core + Table Valued Functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, breeze

I have a TVF (LoadUserInfo) in the DB that is being wired up to return data as per a class (UserInfo) in my .net project.

I am defining an IQueryable as follows:

```
 public IQueryable<UserInfo> LoadUserInfo(Guid? userId) 
    => FromExpression(() => LoadUserInfo(userId));
```

And then for EFCore in my OnModelCreating I setup as follows:

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(AppDatabase).GetMethod(nameof(LoadUserInfo))!);
```

Now in my BreezeController I can easily return info directly from my TVF

```
  public IEnumerable<ReportInfo> UserInfos() {
    return PersistenceManager.Context.LoadUserInfo(User.GetUserId());
  }
```

The above works fine in terms of returning data from the API and also all metadata is correctly generated - ie even my UserInfo class is generated for use on the client side.

**The problem** is that when the metadata is returned during the API call it does NOT include typeinformation for UserInfo, it ignores it completely. I realized this was probably because I never declared UserInfo as a DbSet in the dbContext for EF Core. I went ahead and did that...

```
public DbSet<UserInfo> UserInfos => Set<UserInfo>();
```

Now UserInfos is included in the metadata but now when the server tries to return the data from the Breezecontroller it fails with the following message:

```
Invalid column name 'PeriodEnd'.
Invalid column name 'PeriodStart'.
```

Those are standard built in EF Core columns and I am suspecting that since UserInfo is now declared in the dbSet its expecting them to be there. But given that its not a real table, its just a class wired up to a TVF, they don't exist and its failing.

What is the correct way to set this up so that it doesn't fail?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this on the Breeze client.  You don't need to add that `DbSet`.

Although the entity type is not returned in the query results, you can tell the Breeze client what type to expect by using `.toType` in your query:

```js
var query = EntityQuery.from('UserInfos').toType('UserInfo');
```

Alternatively, you can patch the metadata (on the client) to tell Breeze what entity type to expect from that endpoint:

```js
var meta = manager.metadataStore;
meta.setEntityTypeForResourceName('UserInfos', 'UserInfo');
```

See the [Breeze docs](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/query-from.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Steve...the first suggestion did not work, but patching the metadata worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Any suggestions how to handle the Save on the return trip. On the client side it sees the object and a regular Breeze Entity. But on the server side its a DB function and I need to handle the update/save more specifically as its not a real server side table?